# How to call a command in a loop?

Tags: macros, loops

there is a code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
\stringcases
{#1}%
{%
  {a}{so you typed a}%
  {b}{now this is b}%
  {c}{you want me to do c?}%
}%
{[nada]}%
}
\newcommand{\stringcases}[3]{%
\romannumeral
\str@case{#1}#2{#1}{#3}\q@stop
}
\newcommand{\str@case}[3]{%
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\str@case@end{#3}}
{\str@case{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\str@case@end}{}
\long\def\str@case@end#1#2\q@stop{\z@#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}

\end{document}
```

How instead this

```
\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}
```

do something like this

```
\foreach \n in {a,b,c,e} {\dothis{\n}}
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assunming that the input to `\dothis` is exactly one letter long in each case (which holds for this specific example -- so I guess it's the actual use case) you could simply use `\expandafter`: `\foreach \n in {a,b,c,e} {\expandafter\dothis\n}`.

### Full example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
\stringcases
{#1}%
{%
  {a}{so you typed a}%
  {b}{now this is b}%
  {c}{you want me to do c?}%
}%
{[nada]}%
}
\newcommand{\stringcases}[3]{%
\romannumeral
\str@case{#1}#2{#1}{#3}\q@stop
}
\newcommand{\str@case}[3]{%
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\str@case@end{#3}}
{\str@case{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\str@case@end}{}
\long\def\str@case@end#1#2\q@stop{\z@#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {a,b,c,e} {\expandafter\dothis\n\par}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Comment: May be, to be safe, use the braces `\expandafter\dothis\expandafter{\n}\par`.